# Can you use a variable name to reference an Object without using eval()

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, eval, dynamic-variables

So,

I know it is possible to create dynamic keys on an object.

```
const foo = 'bar';
const obj = {
    [foo]: 'this is bar',
};
```

But is it possible to reference objects by a variable value. For instance if we have 3 objects:

```
const obj1 = {}
const obj2 = {}
const obj3 = {}
```

And an array which holds their names

```
const objects = ['obj1', 'obj2', 'obj3'];
```

Can we loop through those names and reference their objects. This won't work:

```
objects.forEach(obj => Object.assign(obj, { extended: true }));
```

But this will:

```
objects.forEach(obj => Object.assign(eval(obj), { extended: true }));
```

But the docs at Mozilla state "**Do not ever use eval!**"

Comment: Why not create an array of the objects instead of using dynamic variables? Something like: `[obj1, obj2, obj3].map(obj => Object.assign(obj, { extended: true }))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you can't.

In JS, there's no way to access or create variables dynamically, unless you `eval` (or the very similar `Function` constructor).

Although the variables created in the global scope with `var` will become properties of the global object and you can access them on it, that's also not recommended (due to the problems arisig with `var`, using reserved names, etc.), and works only in the global scope (which is even worse to mess with).

The best thing you can do is to place these variables into an object instead, and that way you can access them dynamically. JS variables aren't good for that.

Answer (score 0):

So if I've understood you correctly, you have a list of objectKeys, and you want to produce an array of those objects.  Would this work?

```
const objNames = ['obj1', 'obj2', 'obj3' ]
let objects = [];

for(let i = 0; i < objNames.length; i++){

  let tempObj = {};

  tempObj[objNames[i]] = {extended:true}

  objects.push(tempObj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can do it like that.

```js
const obj1 = {id: 1}
const obj2 = {id: 2}
const obj3 = {id: 3}


var objects = ['obj1', 'obj2', 'obj3'].map(element => [element]);

console.log('objects : ', objects)
```

Answer (score 0):

no you can't (without `eval()`) and it's not a good idea because variable name can be modified for example if you use a minifier

I suggest to use an Array

```js
const objects = [{}, {}, {}]
```

or, if name is important, an Object:

```js
const objects = {
  obj1: {},
  obj2: {},
  obj3: {},
};
```

so you can easily iterate it